# Exporting animation to FBX causes some objects to lose animation

Tags: animation, export, .fbx

In my animation, there are 2 separate armatures, one controls the gun and one controls the arms. Whenever I export the animation as an fbx, the gun armature does not export with the animation.
Here's what the animation looks like before exporting:
[image: Correct animation]

Here's what the animation would look like after exporting as an fbx and importing back into blender:
[image: Incorrect animation; gun does not have animation]

the arm's animation works completely fine, but the gun no longer plays an animation.

I've tried some possible fixes, like parenting, baking, keying (locrot), and some export settings. This has never happened before.